# View Won't Return a Result After Looping Through a Collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Should be a super simple question, yet it's dumbfounding me for some reason. My code:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  def index
    @company = current_user.company
  end
end
```

View:

```
<div id='calendar'/>
<%= render 'layouts/footer', object: @company %>
```

Partial:

```
<div id='footer'>
    <% @company.employees do |employee| %>
      <%= employee.email %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

I've tried dropping the `object: @company`, I've used pry to check the passing of variables, to at the controller, view, and partial stage. Outside of the scope of the loop, I am able to pick up these variables, inside I can't.

Repeat: putting binding.pry inside of my employee loop NEVER triggers.

Putting it outside the loop triggers, and can even read the variables:

```
[1] pry(#<#<Class:0x000000063d2498>>)> @company.employees
  Employee Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."company_id" = ?  [["company_id", 1]]
#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Employee id: 1, email: "ilia.reingold
```

Why is my loop suddenly invisible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually never told Rails/Ruby to loop.

```
<div id='footer'>
    <% @company.employees.each do |employee| %>
      <%= employee.email %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Note the `.each` added to the expression

More about each [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Array.html#method-i-each) (linked to an Array class but it'll be the same for an ActiveRecord relation)